# Subset: Area under the curve issue

Tags: auc

I have a large data set of gaseous emissions. For 48 seperate treatments(pots) (each with multiple measurements) I am trying to calculate the area under the curve for the total emission of this gas. However the AUC gives only one area under a curve, and when I try to define it to give me 48 seperate estimates, it doesn't allow it specifically showing an error message of 'Error: unexpected '=' in "for (i="' after the script
 "for (i=1:48)"

and then continues on saying that i is not defined.

How can I fix this?

```
mydata=cbind(time,erate)
newdata <- subset(mydata, time>=0)
install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo)

 #specifying the new data subset and the main variables for the area under curve calculations 
newdata=data.frame(newdata)
yy=newdata$erate
xx=newdata$time
id <- order(xx)


 #using trapezium figures and roll mean from zoo package to estimate AUC
AUC <- sum(diff(xx[id])*rollmean(yy[id],2))
#defining the deferent variables 
aucpot = integer(48)
aucauc = numeric(48)
auctype = integer(48)
aucslurry= integer(48)
aucsoil= integer(48)

 # AUC gives one value but I want 48


 #trying to define i as the first 48 pots (out of 56) so that I will get an AUC for each pot
for (i=1:48)  {
   set=subset(rc, time>=0 & pot==i)
   yy=set$erate
   xx=set$time
   id <- order(xx)

 (AUC <- sum(diff(xx[id])*rollmean(yy[id],2)))
 aucpot[i]=i

}
auc = data.frame(cbind(aucpot, aucauc, auctype, aucslurry, aucsoil)
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is R?

Answer (score 0):

The for loop syntax in R is:

```
for(var in sequence) { 
expression 
}
```

Note the use of `in` instead of `=`.

So your loop should look like :

```
for (i in 1:48) {...
```